# cakephp 3 - passing dates with json

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Cakephp3, I am passing data to another page using Json, my issue seems to be on my new page where my created date is passed as a sting , and displays like '2016-05-16T17:21:10+0000' . How do i format that string to be left with '2016-05-16' ? I've tried setting it as a date, i tried using the i18nFormat with no success.

```
$http = new Client();
$response = $http->get('http://localhost:8383/mb-be/apis/getmaritimemessagelist.json');
$maritimes = $response->json['content'];
$cnt = count($maritimes);

for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {    
    //var_dump($maritimes[$i]);
    echo '<p class="brdr-bttm mrgn-lft-md ">';
    echo  $this->Html->link($maritimes[$i]['title'], array(
            'controller' => 'messages',
            'action' => 'view/'. $maritimes[$i]['id']
        ));
     echo '<br />';

     $date = $maritimes[$i]['created'];
     echo $date; 
     echo '</p>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of this problem.
Here you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to format your `created date`. but it still has a problem with `T` inside the date `'2016-05-16T17:21:10+0000'`, just because of timezone(I guess).

you can replace this `T` with `space` and got formatted `created date` as you want.

```
$http = new Client();
$response = $http->get('http://localhost:8383/mb-be/apis/getmaritimemessagelist.json');
$maritimes = $response->json['content'];
$cnt = count($maritimes);

for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {    
    //var_dump($maritimes[$i]);
    echo '<p class="brdr-bttm mrgn-lft-md ">';
    echo  $this->Html->link($maritimes[$i]['title'], array(
            'controller' => 'messages',
            'action' => 'view/'. $maritimes[$i]['id']
        ));
     echo '<br />';

     $date = $maritimes[$i]['created'];

        //--------- Format created date --------
    $string =  str_replace("T"," ",$date);

    $created_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:sO',$string)->format('Y-m-d');

    echo $created_date;
     echo '</p>'; 
}
```